# repetition within a sample sequence in R

Tags: r, random, sequence

I am trying to create a vector that contains a number sequence based on a random sample between 1 and 15.  The below code obviously generates a list of these numbers, and 'each=x' determines how often a number is repeated.

```
rep(sample(1:15),2, each=5)
```

However, I would like to have more control over the repetition step - i.e. have each number appear a random number of times, not merely the same amount each time.

I would appreciate your help here

Answer (score 0):

Per Andrie's comment:

```
rep(sample(1:5), sample(1:5))
```